# Error casting object MethodSignature. Spring AOP

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop

Thanks in advance for your support.
Currently I´m stuck in the next problem. I developed an Aspect class to validate my input JSON from al the pkg of RestController. 
Complying with certain characteristics. 
Each method of my controllers returns a different DTO object. 
I created a new generic object to return it from my aspect, when my logic is not fulfilled. When I do tests, I get an error of CannotCastClass "xxxxDTO" to newErrorResponseDTO. 
Currently I already can obtain the method signature or the object type. My idea is to cast the return type (from methodSignature) to my new DTOResponse. The object response is always different. 
I mention that the architecture and design of the total project was already developed. I only did the aspect
At the moment, I have not succeeded.
I attach evidence. Thanks

I tried ResponseAdvice, and multiple ways to cast objects. 
I prefer to stay in the aspect. I get the solution changing all the response DTO in controller to Object generic. Asumming that doing is bad practice, i prefer real solution

```java
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Arrays;

// Other imports missing...

@Aspect
@Component("validateParameterAspect")
public class ValidatorParameterAspect {

  public static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ValidatorParameterAspect.class);

  @Autowired
  ServiciosRest servicio;

  @Pointcut("execution(* com.actinver.rest.*.* (..))")
  public void executeController() {}

  @Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)")
  public void logRequestMapping() {}

  @Around("logRequestMapping() && executeController() && args(..,@RequestBody requestBody) ")
  public Object logRequestBody(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Object requestBody) throws Throwable {
    String vlDataDecrypt = "";

    try {
      // output = joinPoint.proceed();

      System.out.println("--------------123------------");
      logger.warn("Entering in Method :  " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
      logger.warn("Class Name :  " + joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName());
      logger.warn("Arguments :  " + Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));
      logger.warn("Target class : " + joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName());

      SimpleJSONDataContainer args = (SimpleJSONDataContainer) joinPoint.getArgs()[0];

      MethodSignature sign = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
      Class<?> ret = sign.getReturnType();
      String returnString = sign.getReturnType().getName();

      logger.warn("Signature : " + ret);

      vlDataDecrypt = AESHelper.decrypt(servicio.getSeedWord(), args.getData());

      logger.info(" Decrypt -> " + vlDataDecrypt);
      logger.info("args " + args.getData());

      ErrorDataResponse res = validDataEmpty(args.getData());

      if (res.getResult() == "2") {
        return res; // or cast Class<?>

        //return ret.cast(res);
      }

    } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.error("Stack trace -> ", e);
    }
    return joinPoint.proceed();
  }

  public ErrorDataResponse validDataEmpty(String vlDataDecrypt) {
    ErrorDataResponse errorDto = new ErrorDataResponse();

    if (vlDataDecrypt == null || vlDataDecrypt.hashCode() == "77631826690E45839D7B49B932CBC81B".hashCode()
      && vlDataDecrypt.equalsIgnoreCase("77631826690E45839D7B49B932CBC81B")) {
      errorDto.setResult("2");
      errorDto.setMensaje(RestValidatorUtil.EnumErrors.ERROR_INPUT.getMsg());
      logger.info("JSON null" + errorDto.getResult());
      return errorDto;

    }
    return errorDto;
  }
}
```

```java
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

// Other imports missing...

@RestController
@RequestMapping("inicio")
public class Bursanet {
  public final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Bursanet.class);

  @RequestMapping(
    value = "cashByDate",
    method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST },
    consumes = "application/json",
    produces = "application/json"
  )
  public CashByDateDTO cashByDate(
    @RequestBody SimpleJSONDataContainer simpleJSONDataContainer,
    Authentication authentication
  ) {
    String vlDataDecrypt = "";
    CashByDateDTO outJson = new CashByDateDTO();
    CashByDateRequest request = null;
    try {
      UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken userPasswordAuthenticationToken =
        (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken)
          ((OAuth2Authentication) authentication).getUserAuthentication();
      //////example
      return outJson;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I fixed indentation and adjusted code formatting a bit, split code into one chunk per class and also added some imports. After your cut-off `try` block I also added a dummy `catch` block. At least now the code is a bit more readable. What you are asking still remains a mystery to me, can you maybe edit the prose in the question? If I find out I will try to answer, got to read again. The text is so chaotic, sorry, no offense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very difficult to analyse your code because you are not providing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

- There are no package names in your classes.
- There are no imports either.
- You use several project-specific classes (not part of the Spring Framework) the code of which you also don't share here.
- There is no Spring configuration either.

So I have to make some educated guesses here. From what I can see, I can tell you this:

- If you expect `ValidatorParameterAspect.logRequestBody(..)` to intercept execution of `Bursanet.cashByDate(..)`, it should not work because

  - in `args(.., @RequestBody requestBody)` you are expecting that parameter to be the last one in the target method's signature, but actually in `Bursanet.cashByDate(..)` it is the first one. So the pointcut should never match.
  - Again in `args(.., @RequestBody requestBody)` you ought to use a fully qualified class name, i.e. `args(.., @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody requestBody)`.
- Please also note that `execution(* com.actinver.rest.*.* (..))` only matches methods in classes residing directly in the `com.actinver.rest` package, not in any subpackages. If you want to include those too, you need to change the pointcut to `execution(* com.actinver.rest..* (..))`.
- In your question you mention you only want to intercept REST controllers, but you do not limit pointcut matching to classes with a `@RestController` annotation. You could do that via `@within(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController)`. Right now you are doing it indirectly by only relying on methods with `@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)`, which will also work as long as those methods only occur in `@RequestController` classes. Probably this is the case in your application, I am just mentioning it as a detail.
- Instead of `SimpleJSONDataContainer args = (SimpleJSONDataContainer) joinPoint.getArgs()[0];`, why don't you bind the first argument to a `SimpleJSONDataContainer` parameter via `args()` and then just use the currently unused `requestBody` advice method parameter in your code? Something like this:

```java
  @Around("logRequestMapping() && executeController() && args(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody requestBody, ..)")
  public Object logRequestBody(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, SimpleJSONDataContainer requestBody) throws Throwable {
    // (...)

      vlDataDecrypt = AESHelper.decrypt(servicio.getSeedWord(), requestBody.getData());

      logger.info(" Decrypt -> " + vlDataDecrypt);
      logger.info("args " + requestBody.getData());

      ErrorDataResponse res = validDataEmpty(requestBody.getData());

    // (...)
  }
```

- You define `MethodSignature sign = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();` but don't use it above several times where you repeatedly call `joinPoint.getSignature()`, too. Instead you could just reorganise the code like this:

```java
      MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();

      System.out.println("--------------123------------");
      logger.warn("Entering in Method :  " + methodSignature.getName());
      logger.warn("Class Name :  " + methodSignature.getDeclaringTypeName());
      logger.warn("Arguments :  " + Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));
      logger.warn("Target class : " + joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName());

      Class<?> ret = methodSignature.getReturnType();
      String returnString = methodSignature.getReturnType().getName();
```

- I never understood why so many people call many `JoinPoint` methods in order to extract details for logging if instead they could simply log the joinpoint instance. This would show the type of pointcut (e.g. `execution()`) as well as the target method signature. Okay, if you want to list all method arguments, you can do this additionally, but how about this, wouldn't that be enough?

```java
      logger.warn(joinPoint);
//      logger.warn("Entering in Method :  " + methodSignature.getName());
//      logger.warn("Class Name :  " + methodSignature.getDeclaringTypeName());
      logger.warn("Arguments :  " + Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));
//      logger.warn("Target class : " + joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName());
```

- This whole code block I guess you can also remove. It even prints wrong information and calls the return type "signature":

```java
      Class<?> ret = methodSignature.getReturnType();
      String returnString = methodSignature.getReturnType().getName();
      logger.warn("Signature : " + ret);
```

Now for the part which is probably your problem:

```java
      ErrorDataResponse res = validDataEmpty(requestBody.getData());
      if (res.getResult() == "2") {
        return res; // or cast Class<?>
        //return ret.cast(res);
      }
```

Here you are making the aspect advice skip the `joinPoint.proceed()` call and return another object instead. The method you intercept has the signature `public CashByDateDTO cashByDate(..)`, i.e. it returns a specific DTO type. If you want to return an `ErrorDataResponse` instead, this would only work if `ErrorDataResponse` was a subtype of `CashByDateDTO`, which probably it is not. From the class names I would even say that a `*Response` and a `*DTO` are completely different object types. Your advice cannot just change or ignore the method signature. You have to return a `CashByDateDTO` object, no matter what. If you cannot do that here, maybe you are intercepting the wrong method or trying to do the wrong thing in your aspect.

Sorry for the lengthy reply, but there is so much chaos in your code, I had to point out some details.

Comment: @kriagaex thanks for your response. I'm here, and I asked to learn :) As I say before this code it was completely made. My main function in this consulting is maintenance. Indeed you clear so many doubts

Comment: Besides, string comparison via `==` is also a bad idea. Instead of `res.getResult() == "2"`  you should rather write `res.getResult().equals("2")` or, even better, you ought to code defensively and assume that the method result could be `null` (yielding a `NullPointerException` when calling `equals(..)` on it). Then you would write `"2".equals(res.getResult())` which avoids NPE in any case.

Comment: @kriagaex Thank you very much you were a great help. I am already making the changes point by point. Regards